# String.matches() doesn't apply regex

Tags: java, regex

I have next email: `mail-q7hplbmer93rhtzxyd85-4m3fscngz5c9xwzy63db-event@mydomain.com`
and I am checking it by regex:

```
    if(email.matches("mail-[A-Z0-9]+-[A-Z0-9]+-event@mydomain.com")) {
        return true;
    }
```

But this regex never match. (in javascript it works perfect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a case insensitive pattern or modify your regex to support lower case letters. To get a case insensitive [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile-java.lang.String-int-) use:

```
String email = "mail-q7hplbmer93rhtzxyd85-4m3fscngz5c9xwzy63db-event@mydomain.com";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("mail-[A-Z0-9]+-[A-Z0-9]+-event@mydomain.com", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
System.out.println(pattern.matcher(email).matches());
```

Output:

> true

Answer (score 4):

Usually, without modifying default behavior, regular expression are case sensitive...

'q' is **not** between 'A' and 'Z'...